# Python/Flask/HTML and random random length variables output

Tags: python, html, list, random, flask

Python/Flask/HTML

Code I have below does two things I wanted to achieve:

1)Produces random lenght output from randomly choosen, previously defined list of variables and shows it in html.

for instance (output):

apple orange

apple

apple orange orange

I do not want however for fruits to repeat in produced output, keeping everything else as it is.

So I want to prohibit

"apple orange orange"

from happening

How can it be achieved?

Code below:

app.py

```
    from flask import Flask, render_template
    import os
    import random

    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/')

def main():
    z=randint(1, 4)
    Hash1="apple"
    Hash2="orange"
    Hash3="banana"
    Hash4="watermelon"
    fruits = [Hash1, Hash2,Hash3, Hash4]
    a=[choice(fruits) for x in range(z)]
    a=a

    return render_template ('show.html', a=a)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run(host=os.getenv('IP', '0.0.0.0'),port=int(os.getenv('PORT', 8080)))
```

show.html

```
    <html>

    <title>App</title>

    </head>


     <body>

     <h2>your fruits are {{ a }}  </h2>


     </body>


     </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`random.choice` can return an item that has already been selected before. To return unique samples, use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
...
z = random.randint(1, len(fruits))
a = random.sample(fruits, z)
return render_template('show.html', a=a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `random.sample(population, k)`, which samples a population randomly without replacement (i.e. not repeats).

```
a = random.sample(fruits, z)
```